# SAS equivalent of rleid function

Tags: sas, grouping

The R package `data.table` has a function `rleid` which assigns an integer to each element of a vector, with contiguous same-value elements getting the same integer. Hopefully this example in R explains what `rleid` does, here `y` is `rleid(x)`.

```
library(data.table)
ex <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1))
ex$y <- rleid(ex$x)
print(ex)

#    x y
# 1  1 1
# 2  1 1
# 3  4 2
# 4  4 2
# 5  1 3
# 6  3 4
# 7  3 4
# 8  4 5
# 9  4 5
# 10 4 5
# 11 1 6
```

What's the best way to create `y` in SAS for the below data set? (Here `x` is the same as in the R example)

```
data ex;
input x;
cards;
1
1
4
4
1
3
3
4
4
4
1
;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `BY` statement with `NOTSORTED` option.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by x notsorted ;
  y + first.x ;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use BY group processing here to add the counters. BY group has an option called NOTSORTED that will allow you to consider groups that are out of logical order.

```
data want;
    set ex;
    by x notsorted;
    if first.x then count+1;
run;
```

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Answer (score 1):

one more way to do this.

```
  data b;
  set ex;
  if lag(x)=x then count+0;
  else count+1;
  run;
```